# Obrigado, viu? What's "viu"?

Tags: português-brasileiro, perguntas

In Brazil, almost everyone says "Obrigado, viu?" (? to indicate rising intonation).

I asked some Brazilians about what "viu" is supposed to mean and most said it's **just something you say**, although some suggested that it is the **past tense of *ver***, as in "Thanks, did you see that?". Thinking about it, I think it's more likely to be a contraction of the **past tense of *ouvir***, as in *(ou)viu*. So I'd like to ask: What's the "viu" in "Obrigado, viu?" really and what is it supposed to mean?

Comment: "Viu só como aquele sorvete é legal?" - Really it is "ver", not "ouvir" IMHO.

Comment: @VictorStafusa that "viu" is different :P

Comment: Note that this is most used on the northeast part of brazil. (but you can see/hear this on other parts as well)

Comment: @bigow Obrigado por avisar, viu?

Comment: @VictorStafusa ouvi :D Curiosamente aqui o "viu" pode ser melhor, porque não é falado e sim lido.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In this context it's an interjection showing some kind of sympathy, and/or asking for confirmation that the other person heard and understood.

For instance (the confirmation case):

> *Preciso que você termine isso hoje, viu?*
>   I need that you finish this today, understood?

And the sympathy case (yours):

> *Obrigado, viu?*
>   I thank you, okay?

Comment: Eu acho que é uma utilização errada do português, no máximo deveria ser *ouviu*.

Comment: No Brasil é bem comum. Acho que seria uma contração de *ouviu*.

Comment: Cigano eu sei que é bem comum, mas ser comum não quer dizer que esteja certo.

Comment: Oh, meu deus, @JorgeB.... se é uma utilização errada do "português", vamos precisar chamar a língua daquele lado do Atlântico de "brasileiro".

Comment: @brasofilo eu não disse que era errado.

Comment: @JorgeB.  Disse, sim, Jorge.  No primeiro comentário que foi feito. "é uma utilização errada do português"

Comment: Aqui no brasil é como isso, o ´viu´ é como um pedido confinação ao ato de agradecer não tem nada com relação a ver ou ouvir é só um expressão.

Answer (score 16):

**"Viu" in such a context as "obrigado, viu?" is just a filler and means nothing at all.**  There are other words we use in such phrases and they are fillers as well.  See the following:

- **Obrigado, viu?**
- **Obrigado, Tá?**
- **Obrigado, hein?**
- **Obrigado, ok?**

In my **personal opinion**, "obrigado, **viu**?" sounds a little more grateful than a simple "obrigado" and I often use it.

**In other contexts**, just like the one mentioned in another answer ("Eu preciso que esse relatório esteja pronto amanhã, viu?), **it's used to emphasize an order or request and means "understood?"**

The president of **a certain Latin American country** has become notorious for being caught saying "tem que manter isso, **viu**?" in relation to bribery.

In the spoken language a filler is a word or sound filling a pause. In Portuguese there is a long list of words often used as fillers. e.g.

- **sabe...**
- **bem...**
- **humm...**
- **olha...**.
- **oh...**

Comment: You're right, sorry, even the "emphasis" aspect is there... Deleting my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

This is very common in Brazilian Portuguese, and so is it's equivalent in English.

"Thanks a lot, unh?

"
 or huh? where the unh (a kind of grunted assent) emphasizes what precedes it. **It is an interjection. We have the same exact thing in English, I am just not sure how to write it unambiguously, but I am sitting here typing and saying it to myself**.

That unh can be called conversation grunts, even though in Portuguese the viu comes from ouvir and **could also be translated as**: "you hear?" or "ya hear?"

And viu, **can have lexical meaning depending on context**:

"Não vou fazer  isso, viu?"

"I won't do that, see"?

viu, get it, see what I mean, unh, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like "viu" in Brazilian Portuguese is used in a similar fashion to "eh" in Canadian English....it can soften a comment by asking the person to weigh in on a subject, to indicate you don't understand something,or don't believe something is true.

Comment: Hey, welcome. What are you basing your answer on; do you have experience with Portuguese? Your hypothesis differs quite a lot from the earlier answers (and from my own take on it, that it's essentially adding emphasis).